# How to get mac address of the host?

Tags: java, virtual

In a virtual machine environment, I can use sigar to get the virtual machine's mac address, but how to get `mac` address of the host?

Comment: You  never know whether you are in a BOX

Answer (score 0):

try to use `NetworkInterface`, 
all is explain here : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-mac-address-in-java/

Comment: this won't help to get it from host.

Comment: oh, sorry, i didn't get the problem
However, i think this is not possible to know the host's mac address because of java can't know if it is executed in a box

Comment: yes, I agree. At least not in a trivial way which wouldn't need some "hacking".